# jQuery code not working when included in functions.php

Tags: php, functions, wp-enqueue-script, actions

I feel like I am definitely missing something simple here... but for the life of me, can't find what I'm missing.

I am of the "bad habit" of including jQuery functions directly in the header.php file (among other spots). This is frowned upon, as I understand, and functions should be kept in a separate file using the wp_enqueue function to load them (if I get that correctly).

I have this simple function in my header.php that should fire on document ready:

```
<script>
    // Scroll to Top
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        // Force element to hidden state when page loads
        jQuery('.scroll-to-top').hide();

        // Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                jQuery('.scroll-to-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                jQuery('.scroll-to-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });
        //Click event to scroll to top
        jQuery('.scroll-to-top').click(function () {
            jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

So to do things "correctly", I take my code out and placed it in myScripts.js (removing script tags of course). I've created a functions.php file specific to my theme, and I've added this code:

```
<?php
    function add_my_script() {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'myScripts', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myScripts.js', // this is the location of your script file
            array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
        );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
?>
```

But when I load my page, the script doesn't work anymore.   It's been working fine the "wrong"  way for months now, but I'd really like to get it working as it should before I keep adding other scripts to the site.    Any thoughts on what I'm missing here?   Do I need another line / call somewhere to activate the script?

Comment: are you using a child theme?

Comment: The code looks right, have you verified the `myScripts.js` is loaded in the browser?

Comment: @Milo I am using a child theme.  The functions.php is included in the child theme folder, as is the js file.

Comment: Change `get_template_directory_uri` to `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')`

Comment: @Waldermort I'd wondered how to tell if it's loaded..  when I view the page source, I don't see myScripts.js loaded, but then I also don't see the functions.php, so I'm guessing I wouldn't be able to see it that way?

Comment: @Waldermort gave get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') a shot...  same results.   Script just doesn't kick off.  Hmm...

Comment: There are many functions that output the same results. To check if browser loaded a file, in FireFox for example, right click select `inspect element` and (for js files) click `debugger`.

Comment: Thanks @Waldermort.   I checked as you mentioned... unfortunately, my script file is not shown (which would explain why it's not working haha).

Comment: OK. Now check your source file for a `script` tag that should have the full URL of the js file to load. Check that URL against the path to the file. It's probably just a miss-spelled name somewhere (think case sensitive).

Comment: @Waldermort yeah, that's the problem (or appears to be).  There is no `script` tag looking for the `myScripts.js` file.   It doesn't appear it's even trying to load it.

Comment: Hmm, OK. It could be that the main theme is unsetting your action. Try hooking `wp_head` and `echo`ing the full script tag. Copy another from your source and change the file.

Comment: I tested your exact code (in a parent theme), and it works as expected. Are you **sure** this exists `http://example.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/js/myScripts.js` ? Also, please don't cross-post questions, ask WP related stuff here and other programming related at [so].

Comment: Have you included `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in your document head, immediately before the closing HTML `</head>` tag?

Comment: @ChipBennett yes, this was in the header.php of the template.

Comment: Thanks for the help all...  but I've given up on this.   Based on all the answers / suggestions given, it appears that I'm doing everything correctly, but it still isn't working.   I've wasted 6-8 hours attempting to "fix" something that wasn't really broken...  so I've decided to continue doing things the way I was before (putting scripts right in to the header.php file).   This works for me...  maybe someday I will revisit this and attempt to do it the "right" way, but right now the "right" way seems like a ridiculous pain in the rear haha.    Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 3):

When using a child theme, [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) returns the URI of the *parent theme*, you want to swap that for [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), which will load assets from your child theme directory.

Comment: Hmmm that's a good tip to know!   I made the change...  still no luck getting the code to work though.   I've got to be missing something silly... :(

Comment: perhaps a silly question, but is your file in a directory named `js`?

Comment: @Milo It appears his `<script>` tags are not being added to his page.

Comment: Yes, I double checked file locations and such.   Everything seems right.   Oh well...  need to take a break, thanks for the help so far you guys.   I will check back in later...  why is doing this RIGHT so hard, and doing things wrong so EASY???   Haha...

Answer (score 1):

If the `<script>` tags are not on the page with a full path to the .js file, it could be that somewhere in your theme there is a call to `remove_all_actions('wp_enqueue_scripts')`. If this is the case you can try adding the tags manually

```
function add_my_script() {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='" . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/myScripts.js'></script>";
}    
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_my_script', 20 );
```

Note the `20` is to give it a very low priority as you want WP to add it's `jquery` script tags before your own.

Comment: Unfortunately, even forcing this in there still did not work.   While the `<script>` tag did finally show up in the source code, the actual code was still not working.   I'm not sure why it won't work when it's not included directly in the header.php file, but I've decided to just keep going with what I was doing before.   I've, unfortunately, spent way too much time trying to "fix" something that was never really broken.    Thanks again for the help.